# How Do I edit a message in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

The code below is for discord.py v1.4.0

I tried multiple things looking up in the documentation but it just doesn't seem to work I don't know why. Can someone please help me with this.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def balance(ctx):
  boolean = hypixelSkyblockBank.updateBalance()

  embed = discord.Embed(
    title = "Bank Balance",
    color = discord.Color.orange()
  )

  with open('dataStorage.txt', 'r') as inputt:
    dataStorage = eval(inputt.read())

  if boolean:
    embed.add_field(name='Total Balance', value='{:,.1f}'.format(round(dataStorage['balance'], 1)), inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='LaterKids:', value='{:,.1f}'.format(round(dataStorage['LaterKids'], 1)), inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name='LaterIdiot:', value='{:,.1f}'.format(round(dataStorage['LaterIdiot'], 1)), inline=True)
  else:
    embed.add_field(name='Error', value="Hypixel Skyblock API is out of reach.", inline=False)
  
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
  
  repeat = 0
  time.sleep(5)
  while True:
    boolean = hypixelSkyblockBank.updateBalance()
    if boolean:
      embed.set_field_at(0, name='Total Balance', value='{:,.1f}'.format(round(dataStorage['balance'], 1)), inline=False)
      embed.set_field_at(1, name='LaterKids:', value='{:,.1f}'.format(round(dataStorage['LaterKids'], 1)), inline=True)
      embed.set_field_at(2, name='LaterIdiot:', value='{:,.1f}'.format(round(dataStorage['LaterIdiot'], 1)), inline=True)
    else:
      repeat += 1
      if repeat == 1:
        embed.clear_fields()
        embed.add_field(name='Error', value="Hypixel Skyblock API is out of reach.", inline=False)
      else:
        embed.set_field_at(0, name='Error', value="Hypixel Skyblock API is out of reach.", inline=False)
    await ctx.edit(embed=embed)
    time.sleep(10)
```

When running this it gives me an error:

```
Bot is ready
[]
Total Balance: 13561217.227630626
LaterKids: 84047.0
LaterIdiot: 13477170.227630626
Timestamp: 1595896376010
[]
Total Balance: 13561217.227630626
LaterKids: 84047.0
LaterIdiot: 13477170.227630626
Timestamp: 1595896376010
Ignoring exception in command balance:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Name\Desktop\Python-Projects\hypixel skyblock bank record\env\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 83, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:/Users/Name/Desktop/Python-Projects/hypixel skyblock bank record/discordBOT.py", line 54, in balance
    await ctx.edit(embed=embed)
AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'edit'
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Name\Desktop\Python-Projects\hypixel skyblock bank record\env\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "c:\Users\Name\Desktop\Python-Projects\hypixel skyblock bank record\env\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 797, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\Name\Desktop\Python-Projects\hypixel skyblock bank record\env\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 92, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'edit'
```

Comment: Please format your errors as code.

Comment: It dosent let me do the errors in code format since it says i need to add more details but i dont think there are any more details to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use a `edit` attribute on a `Context` object. When you send the message, you want to assign it to a variable

```
my_custom_message_variable = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

then at the end when you try to edit the message, you want to use the `edit` attribute on the custom variable which is holding your message object.

```
await my_custom_message_variable.edit(embed=embed)
```

---

As a side note, import `asyncio` and start using `asyncio.sleep(seconds)` as `time.sleep` is blocking. Which will stop your bot from processing anything else until the time delay is over.

Comment: Thank you very much I am a not used to discord.py very much and I don't know what the context object is so thanks.